# how to hide div in smartphone or mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to hide my div if someone visit from smartphone, mobile etc. my javascript code not work for me, please let me know how to fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|pocket|psp|kindle|avantgo|blazer|midori|Tablet|Palm|maemo|plucker|phone|BlackBerry|symbian|IEMobile|mobile|ZuneWP7|Windows Phone|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
     document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = 'none';
     };
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mybox">
Hello world
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use CSS `@media queries` to hide any div. By using media query you can target the any device.

Comment: CSS media Query is the answer for your question. Read article to know more http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/05/building-a-better-responsive-website/

Comment: The problem is (I think so) that the code is executed before your html div element has been renderized, if you move the code to the end of your html file It should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use media query to create responsive UI,

For different screen resolution you should have different `CSS` for all your HTML component(Could be Div/CSS Class etc.)

Search for some good responsive tutorial you'll surely find that interesting

Now a days people using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to make the UI responsive, It has many responsive classes those are more useful to create Rapid responsive UI development.
Sample

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use media query to hide

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
#mybox{
display: none
}
```

This will hide when screen size below 480px

Comment: Actually, i want mobile, smartphone, not view this div, tablet, pc are able to see this div...

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the window.onload

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|pocket|psp|kindle|avantgo|blazer|midori|Tablet|Palm|maemo|plucker|phone|BlackBerry|symbian|IEMobile|mobile|ZuneWP7|Windows Phone|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
     window.onload = function (){
         document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = 'none';
     }
   };
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mybox">
Hello world
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But the css approach seems cleaner.

Comment: window.onload mean, when full document load on device, mybox div need to be hidden? right?

Comment: Yes. The "problem" with your code is that, when script tag is loaded the div it's not loaded.

I really think the css approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon of if condition close block:

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|pocket|psp|kindle|avantgo|blazer|midori|Tablet|Palm|maemo|plucker|phone|BlackBerry|symbian|IEMobile|mobile|ZuneWP7|Windows Phone|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
     document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = 'none';
     }//semicolon is removed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide or show someone on any screen by [**media queries**](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .div{
        display : block; For big screen
    }
}
@media (min-width: 380px) and (max-width: 420px) {
    .div{
        display : none; For small screen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hello my friend try this..

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) 
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: none;
        }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px)
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: none;
        }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) 
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: none;
        }
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: none;
        }
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) 
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: none;
        }
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) 
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: none;
        }
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px)
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: block;
        }
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px)
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: block;
        }
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) 
{
        #mybox
        {
            display: none;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your JS code at the end of the page or use an `onLoad` event.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mybox">
Hello world
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|pocket|psp|kindle|avantgo|blazer|midori|Tablet|Palm|maemo|plucker|phone|BlackBerry|symbian|IEMobile|mobile|ZuneWP7|Windows Phone|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
     document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = 'none';
     };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```